# Mule reprocessing a failed message twice during start up

Tags: persistence, mule

I am working with Mule 3.3.1. I have an queue flow with File Persistent storage.

```
<vm:connector name="vmConnector" createMultipleTransactedReceivers="true" numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers="20">
    <vm:queue-profile maxOutstandingMessages="500000" >
        <file-queue-store/>
    </vm:queue-profile>
</vm:connector>

<vm:endpoint name="firstQueue" path="someFirstQueue" exchange-pattern="one-way" connector-ref="vmConnector" />
```

I put messages on a queue which is read by a flow to make an outbound call to tcServer. When a call comes in, I see a file in queuestore. The outbound http call takes 30 seconds (intentional). I shutdown my Mule server during the outbound call. I see the message is still in queuestore.

When I start Mule server again, I see two calls being made to tcServer on startup. Any ideas?

I can provide more details if needed.

Comment: After shutdown, do you see one or several messages in the queuestore directory?

Comment: Not to be alarming but this feels like a bug then :'( Do you mind filing a JIRA with MuleSoft - http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE - providing all what's needed to reproduce the issue. Also they'll want to know if the problem is still there in 3.4.0: could you try the same experiment on 3.4.0?

Comment: Created an Issue. http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6867

Comment: Did you get a chance to try on 3.4.0?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have access to 3.4.0 :(

Comment: It's OK, I'm reproducing the issue on 3.4.0.